# sudo nrpe sorry you must have a tty to run sudo

Tags: nagios, sudo, nrpe

After reading this

```
[root@wcmisdlin02 alexus]# tail -2 /etc/sudoers
## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
[root@wcmisdlin02 alexus]#
```

I now have following:

```
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]# cat /etc/sudoers.d/01_nagios 
Defaults:nagios !requiretty
nagios      ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:   /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]#
```

yet I'm getting in my `/var/log/messages`

```
Sep 21 11:14:32 wcmisdlin02 sudo:     nrpe : sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_load -w 6,5,4 -c 8,7,6
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that NRPE is running as `nagios` user.

If you run it as a standalone service:

```
ps -ef | grep nrpe
grep nrpe_user /path/to/nrpe.cfg
```

Or if you run it via TCP wrapper:

```
grep user /etc/xinetd.d/nrpe
```

Comment: you were right, new nagios's nrpe now uses nrpe user instead of nagios user, so as soon as i changed nagios to nrpe it start working right away, thanks!

Comment: @voretaq7 I was trying to do so, it wouldn't allow me to do so, it said it was too soon, i gotta wait for 2 minutes, so now after 2 minutes later i accept it as an answer

Comment: ah, I forgot about that timeout :-)