# Nagios NRPE unable to read output on remote system only

Tags: linux, nagios

I'm running NRPE on a server with the check_disk command. I have setup sudo and the command works ok as the nagios user on the server.

```
command[check_disk]=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 10% -c 5% -x /dev/cdrom -x /dev/shm -x /nfs01 -x /nfshome -x /mnt/hlmon01/shared -x /mnt/hlmon01/shared -A -i '.gvfs'

/usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 10% -c 5% -x /dev/cdrom -x /dev/shm -x /nfs01 -x /nfshome -x /mnt/hlmon01/shared -x /mnt/hlmon01/shared -A -i '.gv fs' 
DISK OK - free space: / 44730 MB (93% inode=98%); /boot 351 MB (78% inode=99%); /var/lib/xenstored 5593 MB (99% inode=99%); /poolfsmnt/0004fb0000050000577933960ee5846b 102134 MB (99% inode=99%); /OVS/Repositories/0004fb0000030000755a9cd0ee8ac4da 1736686 MB (33% inode=33%);| /=2962MB;45241;47754;0;50268 /boot=95MB;428;452;0;476 /var/lib/xenstored=0MB;5033;5313;0;5593 /poolfsmnt/0004fb0000050000577933960ee5846b=265MB;92160;97280;0;102400 /OVS/Repositories/0004fb0000030000755a9cd0ee8ac4da=3506194MB;4718592;4980736;0;5242880
```

When I run this command on the nagios server I am getting the following error:

```
./check_nrpe -H test_server -c check_disk 
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

Can anyone help me out on how to debug this?

Thanks

Comment: Worth reviewing the suggestions in http://serverfault.com/questions/313959/sudo-nrpe-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo

Comment: Anything in the NRPE log file and/or /var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog? Do other nrpe checks on that host work? Is it just ones that use sudo that fail?

Comment: I verified from the link that nagios is running nrpe.

nagios    1116     1  0 Oct19 ?        00:00:13 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg -d

I have't found anything so far in any logs on either server.

Comment: Possibly the most common nagios question on SF: http://serverfault.com/search?q=%5Bnagios%5D+nrpe+unable+to+read+output

Answer (score 0):

Hi with which user did your run: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 10% -c 5% -x /dev/cdrom -x /dev/shm -x /nfs01 -x /nfshome -x /mnt/hlmon01/shared -x /mnt/hlmon01/shared -A -i '.gv fs' 
?

Try to run this command doing "su - [the user your nagios agent runs]" before.

Comment: I'm running the command as nagios and it works on the server running nrpe. I just can't get the results to return using nrpe on the other server. Other commands are being returned from the other server. I have to run this command as root because of OVM and two mounts that nagios doesn't have permissions to.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be `selinux` stopping `sudo` access from `nrpe`. Try disabling `selinux` temporarily on the server that you're monitoring with

```
setenforce permissive
```

If that makes things work then you need to decide if you're happy just making this permanent or if you're prepared to update the selinux policy to make it work. If you look in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` you should see the denials that are causing the issue.

There's some discussion of related issues here - 
[SELinux prevents Nagios plugins from running on RHEL6](https://serverfault.com/questions/269520/selinux-prevents-nagios-plugins-from-running-on-rhel6) 
That's talking about Red Hat derived distributions, I'm not sure what version of Linux you're using on these systems.

Comment: Selinux is already disabled.